# Flexible widget didn't work on text widget flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to use flexible on my text cause it's overflow but for some reason expanded or neither flexible didn't work. But it work on other text widget on different screen. Anyone know why ? How can I fix this ?

```
return Row(
      children: [
        /// Ticket Details
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            /// Ticket Title
            Flexible(
              child: Text(
                ticketData['title'],
                style: primaryColor700Style.copyWith(
                  fontSize: fontSize18,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 8),

            /// Date Created
            Text(
              'Created : ' +
                  DateFormat('d MMM y').format(
                    DateTime.parse(
                      ticketData['date_created'].toDate().toString(),
                    ),
                  ),
              style: primaryColor400Style.copyWith(
                fontSize: fontSize12,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),

        /// Urgent Icon
        if (ticketData['is_urgent'])
          Icon(
            Icons.warning_rounded,
            size: 35,
            color: warningColor,
          ),
      ],
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the column with flexible

```dart
Row(
 children: [
   Flexible(
    child: Column(
     children:[
      Text(),
     ]
    )
   )
 ]
)
```

Comment: should i still wrap the text with flexible or expanded if i want the text to be not overflow ?

Comment: No that will throw an error if you add flexible inside a column without bounds

Answer (score 0):

`Row` takes infinite width, To get available width row for next children you can wrap `Expanded`/ `Flexibile`/ fixed width widget. You can check [this doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html) more about.

You can find this from Layout algorithm on [Row](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html)

- Expanded, to indicate children that should take all the remaining room.
- Flexible, to indicate children that should share the remaining room but that may by sized smaller (leaving some remaining room unused).